# How do i refresh certain tables whenever a new value is added?

Tags: php

So i have the following code;

```
<div class="content-inbox">   <h3>{{{ trans('texts.top_buy_orders')}}}</h3><div id="orders-b-list">
    <div id="orders_buy_{{{Session::get('market_id')}}}" class="scrolltable">
      <table class="table table-striped hovered">
        <thead>
          <tr class="header-tb"><th>{{{ trans('texts.price')}}}</th><th>{{{ $coinmain }}}</th><th>{{{ $coinsecond }}}</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php $total_amount=0; $total_value=0; ?>
          @foreach($buy_orders as $buy_order)
           <?php
            $total_amount+= $buy_order->total_from_value;
            $total_value+= $buy_order->total_to_value;
            $price = sprintf('%.8f',$buy_order->price);
            $class_price = str_replace(".", "-", $price);
            $class_price = str_replace(",", "-", $class_price);
           ?>
            <tr id="order-{{$buy_order->id}}" class="order price-{{$class_price}}" onclick="use_price(2,<?php echo $buy_order->price ?>,<?php echo $buy_order->total_from_value ?>)" data-sort="{{sprintf('%.8f',$buy_order->price)}}"><td class="price">{{sprintf('%.8f',$buy_order->price)}}</td><td class="amount">{{{sprintf('%.8f',$buy_order->total_from_value)}}}</td><td class="total">{{{sprintf('%.8f',$buy_order->total_to_value)}}}</td></tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this code is that if someone on my site makes an order, it is not automatically updated/displayed in the orderbook. You'll need to manually refresh the entire page to see new orders.

Now i was thinking that something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    $('.View').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).load('/echo/json/', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
}, 15000); // refresh every 15000 milliseconds
  </script>
```

Could work by updating the orderbooks every x seconds for everyone, but that means that it will also refresh when there is no need/ no new orders being added to the orderbook.

Is there a way to only make the div/table refresh when there is a new buy order placed, as opposed to refreshing the div/table every x seconds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better solution, but if you want live data in your webbrowser, you could use [**Websockets**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

I suggest using the [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) library (if you want to use PHP), but there are some other PHP alternatives:

- Apache Module: https://github.com/disconnect/apache-websocket
- Wrench: https://github.com/varspool/Wrench

You could also use a seperate Node server to handle your websockets if you know your way around NodeJS:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-websocket

I find the node server the easiest to setup and use.

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks that you are using Laravel, you can use the build-in [Broadcast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting) functionality to make it happens.

You will need to create an [Event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events) and dispatches it whenever the table is updated, and broadcast it.

Then you will subscribe to that broadcast channel on your front-end, and make an ajax call to reload the data. You can also broadcast just the rows that changed, and just append that rows to your dataset. (keep in mind that some broadcast services have a data size limitation)